# General-purpose CLI compression program with good integrity check in Linux

Tags: linux, archiving, file-compression

As the title says I am in search for a good, defined as *the best available*, general-purpose command-line compression program with good integrity check in Linux.

## These archives will be used for long term storage

**on Blu-ray [M-Disc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-DISC)s; [details on used hardware](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/7956/2059).**

Requirements:

- the better in-built **integrity check**, the better software for my **archiving purposes**
- must be **open-source**
- preferably available in **packaged form** in most distributions, **or better = installed by default**
- adjustable compression ratio, while **using up to 10GB RAM** when compressing
- should be **multi-threaded** as I have 8 core CPU

Comment: Should the integrity check only be a check (for instance including a MD5 in the filename), or should it attempt correction?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul If I understand your question correctly, it would be nice to have the option to attempt recovery.

Comment: checking file integrity and changing compression ratio are the most basic things that all archiving tools must have

Comment: @phuclv I agree, but this question is to what degree certain tools have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading a lot of manual pages, I can recommend the following:

## [xz (man page)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xz)

As it has in-built integrity check adjustable to SHA-256 using the following switch:

```
--check=sha256
```

Further bonuses:

- You may specify the number of CPU threads using the following switch:

  ```
  --threads=8
  ```
- The default compression level switch is set to 6, you may change that to the maximum with:

  ```
  -9
  ```
- It implements a *maximum effort* algorithm using the following switch, though it is rather slow:

  ```
  --extreme
  ```

You can easily define an alias of whatever combination you choose.

---

## Benchmarks

I will add to this section sequentially what I have tested out.

1. `xz` (**multi-threading** + **SHA-256** + **level 9** + **extreme**)

   ```
   alias xz-extreme='xz --format=xz --check=sha256 -9 --threads=8 --keep --verbose --verbose --extreme'
   ```

   With this command the compression took almost **25 minutes** and resulted in **0.772 ratio**.

   ```
   $ xz-extreme data.tar

   7,991.0 MiB / 10.1 GiB = 0.772   7.0 MiB/s      24:28
   ```
2. `xz` (**multi-threading** + **CRC-32** + **default level 6**)

   ```
   alias xz='xz --format=xz --threads=8 --keep --verbose --verbose'
   ```

   With this command the compression took less than **15 minutes** and resulted in **0.786 ratio** (**+138 MiB**).

   ```
   $ xz data.tar

   8,129.8 MiB / 10.1 GiB = 0.786    12 MiB/s      14:15
   ```

## [bzip2 (man page)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bzip2)

In contrast to `xz`, due to its single-threaded nature, the same file with the command:

```
$ bzip2 --keep -9 --verbose data.tar

data.tar:  1.244:1,  6.430 bits/byte, 19.63% saved, 10848870400 in, 8719149908 out.
```

Took exactly **27 minutes** while achieving **0.803 ratio** (**+324MiB**).

---

## Short data analysis of the presented data set

- Further un-compressible files 4.3 GiB (like RAR or 7-Zip on max compression).
- Image (JPEG) files 2 GiB.
- Windows executable installers (means also compressed) 0.8 GiB.
- Only the remaining 3 GiB were more or less well compressible files.

---

## Different data set

- about a 100,000 code files (highly compressible data)
- some PDFs containing JPEG images of text (rather un-compressible)

## Interesting results summary

1. **4.5G** code_and_some_books.**tar**
2. **2.3G** code_and_some_books.tar.**gz** (`-9`)
3. **2.1G** code_and_some_books.tar.**bz2** (`-9`)
4. **1.6G** code_and_some_books.tar.**xz** (the above `xz-extreme` alias used)

Comment: I've tried it on 6.1MB plain text files on a dual-core machine. `tar -cf zzz.tar * && bzip2 -9 zzz.tar` took 1.5s and resulted in a 968k file, while the same with `xz` using your options took 11s and resulted in an 863k file. So `xz` took 7 times as long while offering about 11% better compression with that input. My conclusion: if in a frequent process I want to (temporarily) save some space, I'd rather go with `bzip2` – while for long-time archival, `xz` might be the better choice. Though this conclusion is based on too little data :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort you took (upvoted now). I leave my corrected comment above for an additional example. In everyday life most of us rarely compress such huge amounts as you just did :)